# Installing modules in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, metatrader5

I'm trying to use heroku for a telegram bot with Python.
Everything is going fine except I can't install MetaTrader5 module. 
when I type `git push heroku master` command, the answer in PowerShell is:

```
Enumerating objects: 59, done.
Counting objects: 100% (59/59), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
Writing objects: 100% (59/59), 417.63 KiB | 5.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 59 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.6
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting certifi==2019.11.28
remote:          Downloading certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet==3.0.4
remote:          Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==2.9
remote:          Downloading idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
remote:        Collecting int-date==0.1.8
remote:          Downloading int_date-0.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5==5.0.24 (from -r /tmp/build_4e6218f160af939bdbff3e12742a3458/requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5==5.0.24 (from -r /tmp/build_4e6218f160af939bdbff3e12742a3458/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to telegram-bot-2567.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/telegram-bot-2567.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

In my requirements text I have `MetaTrader5==5.0.24`.
I'm already using this module in my own PC but I can't use it on heroku.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: edit your requirements.txt and remove `MetaTrader5` from `MetaTrader5==5.0.24`. (This is only temporary to see if it would install it.) Also check which Python version you are using locally (`python -V`) and match Heroku's (Python 3.7.6) with your local one (given Heroku still supports that Python).

Comment: My python version is 3.7.6 and I think it's supported by heroku, every other module are installed except for metatrader, i tried it without that ==version but the error is still the same. I don't know why it can't install metatrader and I'm looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

The heroku machine your are trying to install the MetaTrader5 package is linux based.
This package (plus MetaTrader5 Terminal client) is only available for Windows, unless you use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) on linux.

I was getting the same error until I installed the package in a windows environment directly (Using CMD).